# How can I read SOAP message response?

Tags: c#, soap

In the past I've always used class proxy to communicate with WebService.

Now I want to use  SOAP message. I developed a .ddl that do this, and all goes fine.

My question is: Is there any standard (method-code-framework class) that can read and parse the SOAP message response?

Here is an example. I send SOAP message to delete all records.
I get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:removeAllVODResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.cms.guardian">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:Result" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax21="http://dto.ws.cms.guardian/xsd">
            <ax21:message>REMOVED ALL</ax21:message>
            <ax21:type>SUCCESS</ax21:type>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:removeAllVODResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can parse the 2 element message/type to this class:

```
public partial class Result {

    private string messageField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:removeAllVODResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.cms.guardian">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:Result" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax21="http://dto.ws.cms.guardian/xsd">
            <ax21:message>REMOVED ALL</ax21:message>
            <ax21:type>SUCCESS</ax21:type>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:removeAllVODResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: sorry to write the response as comment bacause i can't write it in the post it's always hide

Comment: You need to indent the XML with four spaces. The editor will then treat it as pre-formatted code and not inline HTML.

Comment: How are you receiving the response?